# Where are the exectuables located for the games that come with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I'm looking for the physical location of the executables for the games that come with Windows 7.

Namely things like Minesweeper and Solitaire.  I enjoy reverse engineering these apps as sort of my "hello world" reversing projects.

So, where are the winmine.exe/sol.exe's in the new folder structure of Windows 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games
```